# How to simply collapse (sum) some lines within an array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I want to sum several specific rows in an array, not the whole array.

Say I have an array

```
qq <- array(data = rep(1, 12), dim = c(3,2,2))
```

which looks like

```
    , , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1

   , , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1
```

I want to sum rows 2 and 3 to get

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
```

I can do this reasonably easily but inelegantly by stuffing around by summing the desired rows and placing them and the old rows in a new array, but it seems like a clunky way to do this. E.g.:

```
qq23sum <- apply(X = qq[2:3,,], MARGIN = c(2,3), FUN = sum)

qw <- array(dim = c(2,2,2))

qw[1,,] <- qq[1,,]
qw[2,,] <- qq23sum
```

---

Edit: In response to comment, I would want to sum any arbitrary rows or other dimension in an array, so a more complex example might be:

```
qq <- array(data = rep(1, 12000), dim = c(30, 20, 20))


qq23sum <- apply(X = qq[c(2, 3, 10, 11, 13),,], MARGIN = c(2,3), FUN = sum)

qw <- array(dim = c(26, 20,20))
```

And more stuffing around putting arrays into the right place afterward per above...

---

I feel like there's a elegant solution out there — anyone?

Comment: Will you always need to sum the last n rows or would you need to sum any rows in `1:nrow(qq)`? How would, then, "qw" look like? Can you provide some more complex examples if necessary?

Comment: I'd wan't to sum any arbitrary rows (or other dimension) in the array. Expanded in edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We initialize another array with the new dimensions and then use a `for` loop

```
qq1 <- array(NA, c(2, 2, 3))
for(j in seq(dim(qq1))){
         qq1[,,j] <- rbind(qq[,,j][1,], colSums(qq[,,j][-1,]))
}


qq1
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2

#, , 3

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2
```